# How do I make an externally defined function available in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, function, class

I have a class that I use with the Armadillo package to create a specific kind of matrix. I'm having trouble debugging it, so I would like to use a function I have written called `Matlab_Print`. It lives in its own `.h` and `.cpp` file and is used throughout my code. The class and the function both work perfectly, but I do not seem to be able to combine them.

I have tried `#include "Matlab_Print"` in `SU3.h` both before and after the class definition. I really don't want to make the function a class function as I use `Matlab_Print` frequently. I do have a workaround but it is inconvenient, and at any rate I am looking at this as a learning opportunity.

I trap error messages with a `try` when calling the `SU3` constructor and I get the following:

> error: Mat::init(): size is fixed and hence cannot be changed

```
main.cpp

#include "pch.h"
#include <new>
#include <exception>
#include "SU3.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int icount { 0 };
    SU3 *su3[10];

    try
    {
        for (icount = 0; icount < 10; icount++)
        {
            su3[icount] = new SU3(0.1);
        }
    }
    catch (int param) { cout << "Function " << __func__ << " int " << param << " exception in memory allocation for su3" << std::endl; exit(1); }
    catch (char param) { cout << "Function " << __func__ << " char " << param << " exception in memory allocation for su3" << std::endl; exit(1); }
    catch (...) { cout << "Function " << __func__ << " exception in memory allocation for su3" << std::endl; exit(1); }

    return 0;
}
```

```
SU3.h

#include "pch.h"
#include "SU3.h"
#include <armadillo>
#include "Matlab_Print.h"

class SU3
{
public:
    arma::Mat<cx_double>::fixed<3, 3> *X;
    SU3(const double epsilon);
};
```

```
SU3.cpp

SU3::SU3(const double epsilon)  // simplifed so that epsilon plays no role
{
    const std::complex<double>    o{ 1.0 , 0.0 };    // complex 1
    const std::complex<double>    z{ 0.0 , 1.0 };    // complex 0

    X = new arma::Mat<cx_double>::fixed<3, 3>{ fill::zeros }; //// solution to problem: define and initialize pointer ////

    *X =    {   { o, z, z},
            { z, o, z},
            { z, z, o} };

    Matlab_Print(*X, "SU3");        // this is the line I wish to use
}
```

```
Matlab_Print.h

#include <armadillo>
#include <complex>

void Matlab_Print(arma::Mat<cx_double>::fixed<3, 3> Matrix, std::string T);
```

```
Matlab_Print.cpp

#include "pch.h"
#include "Matlab_Print.h"

void Matlab_Print(arma::Mat<cx_double>::fixed<3, 3> Matrix, std::string T)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "RE = [" << std::real(Matrix(0, 0)) << "   " << std::real(Matrix(0, 1)) << "   " << std::real(Matrix(0, 2)) << ";   ";
    std::cout << std::real(Matrix(1, 0)) << "   " << std::real(Matrix(1, 1)) << "   " << std::real(Matrix(1, 2)) << ";   ";
    std::cout << std::real(Matrix(2, 0)) << "   " << std::real(Matrix(2, 1)) << "   " << std::real(Matrix(2, 2)) << "];  " << std::endl;

    std::cout << "IM = [" << std::imag(Matrix(0, 0)) << "   " << std::imag(Matrix(0, 1)) << "   " << std::imag(Matrix(0, 2)) << ";   ";
    std::cout << std::imag(Matrix(1, 0)) << "   " << std::imag(Matrix(1, 1)) << "   " << std::imag(Matrix(1, 2)) << ";   ";
    std::cout << std::imag(Matrix(2, 0)) << "   " << std::imag(Matrix(2, 1)) << "   " << std::imag(Matrix(2, 2)) << "];  " << std::endl;

    std::cout << T << " = RE + 1i*IM;" << std::endl;
}
```

Thank you for your patience. I hope this is all of the information you need.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I would like to construct a matrix X and then, hopefully, print it out in MATLAB format during runtime. If I #include "Print_Matlab" in SU3.h the program compiles successfully but gives the runtime error I indicated above. If I remove the #include and the function call to Print_Matlab (see below) it compiles and works perfectly (well, it gives me the wrong answer perfectly :) at any rate).

Comment: I hope this clarifies the question without oversimplifying

Comment: Ask a single question at a time and provide all required information for us to be able to help you. As written, there are too many missing information for us to really help you except maybe doing arbitrary guess that might or might not be related to your actual problems. For example, are you sure that you should pass argument by copy to the print function? We cannot really tell because we don't have some part of the code. Also, if you get an error when calling the constructor, tell us at which line of it.

Comment: I hope that my recent edit clarifies the coding problem. This compiles just fine but gives me the runtime error shown above. If I remove all references to Matlab_Print from SU3.h and SU3.cpp it works fine. Unfortunately no line number is given as a reference, but I know from printing icount in the loop in main.cpp that the error happens for icount = 0, so it is bombing on the first constructor call.

Comment: It looks to me like SU3.cpp doesn't include SU3.h and that would explain why you can't use anything in that header file from inside the class.

Comment: You have undefined behavior in `SU3::SU3`, because you are dereferencing `X` without initializing it first.

Comment: The "SU3.h problem that Jerry Jeremiah pointed out turned out to be a cut-and-paste error and was fine in the code. Thanks for catching that! But the initialization of the pointer was the real problem. Thanks uneven_mark for the solution! I've edited it in my post with comments for the next guy.

Answer (score 0):

As @uneven_mark notes, you have undefined behavior in `SU3::SU3`, because you are dereferencing `X` without initializing it first. You probably don't want a pointer here.

N.b. you *don't* need `new` to create objects of class type.

```
class SU3
{
public:
    arma::Mat<cx_double>::fixed<3, 3> X;
    SU3(const double epsilon);
};

using namespace std::literals::complex_literals;

SU3::SU3(const double epsilon)
  : X({ { 1, 1i, 1i },
        { 1i, 1, 1i },
        { 1i, 1i, 1 } }) // prefer member initialisers over assingments
{
    Matlab_Print(X, "SU3");
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, I will try this in the code as well.